# Whole House Humidifier on All-in-One Heat Pump and Freezing Temps

Tags: heat-pump, humidifier

How do I install a whole house humidifier on an all-in-one heat pump in an area where we have freezing temperatures during the time of year when you'd want to use a whole house humidifier.

An HVAC contractor pretty much told us it can't be done but it's hard for me to believe this problem is unique and unsolvable. I'd prefer not using some portable unit that sprays water mist into the air from a water reservoir that needs to be filled throughout the day.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to install a [steam humidifier](http://www.alpinehomeair.com/viewproduct.cfm?productID=453063161&linkfrom=froogle&gclid=CJisoJrRjMoCFYQXHwodTIINWg), and inject steam into the supply duct.  Though to install one, you'll have to have access to the main supply duct inside the home. You'll also as have to have a source of water and power.

Obviously these types of units are available from many manufacturers, and offer a variety of features and pricing. However, in general, this type of unit tends to be more expensive than other types of humidifiers.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explain what method is used to heat your house. i.e. forced air or hot water.

I am going to go out on a limb and say the the HVAC contractor told you that because you have a hot water heating system. If you a have a forced air system with ductwork you could just install a standard whole house humidifier like any other forced air system.

With a hot water heating system, you will need an entirely separate piece of equipment to perform the task of humidifying the air.

Good luck!

Comment: The issue is more that the entire unit (condenser and evaporator) are outside and I live in a zone that experiences hard freezes. Any water line supplying an external humidifier and any drain line from the humidifier will freeze regardless of heat source.